# How can I create a subset of a dataframe with the indices starting at 0?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, subset

I am creating a subset of a dataframe like this:

`dist = df['distance'][23:42]`

The start index of the result I am getting is then 23, but i want to start the series at index 0.

How can I tell Python to create new indices for my subset and not reuse the ones from the initial dataframe?

Comment: add `reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`

> drop : bool, default False
>   Do not try to insert index into dataframe columns. This resets the index to the default integer index.

```
df['distance'].iloc[23:42].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or as @yatu suggests:

```
df.loc[23:42, 'distance'].reset_index(drop=True)
```